# JIRA API to List Jira users added from date

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I want to list all the users who were added from date.I have a code like this

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('<company-jira-url>',
                basic_auth=('username', 'password'))

users = jira.search_users(".")
for user in users:
     jirauser = jira.user(user.name)
     print(jirauser)
```

But i am not able to add query for the date and for project. Is there any other way of listing all the users started from particular date or how can i add query in `search_users`
Thank you in advance!